# Why it is not removing what selected value ? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Why it is not removing what selected value.

```
data = []
data = pd.read_csv(r'summary.csv', low_memory=False, header = None, sep = ',')
to_drop= ['[-11057] Not Enough Values For Calculation',str]
data = data[~data[:].isin(to_drop)]
data = data.dropna(inplace = True)
data.shape
```

And its still not removing the selected value, WHY!

[image]

Comment: You can not use inplace=True and reassign... Just `data.dropna(inplace=True)` or  `data=data.dropna()`.

Comment: could you copy and paste a example of your dataframe?

Comment: @ScottBoston Yes correct. Its ok right now thank you very much!

Comment: @ScottBoston If you found your answer, make sure to click the `close` button by the `edit` button on your post so others in the forum are aware. ;)